# send alamofire request in background, when view controller should be dissmissed

Tags: swift, background, alamofire

I have the function, that should send video position time, when user closes avplayercontroller, here is it:

```
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "networkRequest", attributes: .concurrent)

fileprivate func sendBackgroundRequest(urlString: String, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: Parameters?) {

    let headers = createHeader()

    print(headers)

    if networkManager!.isReachable {

        concurrentQueue.async {

            let request = Alamofire.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)

            request.responseJSON { data in

                if data.result.error == nil {
                    if data.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                        print("Success")
                    } else {
                        print(data.response?.statusCode)
                    }
                } else {
                    print(data.result.error)
                }

            }

        }

    }
}

func sendSeriesDurationTime(provider: String, fileID: String, timePosition: Int) {
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "time_position": timePosition
    ]

    let dataUrl = "\(BASE_URL)\(PLAYED_DURATION_SLUG)\(provider)/\(fileID)"

    print(dataUrl)

    sendBackgroundRequest(urlString: dataUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
}
```

I call it in **viewWillDisappear** method. But when I click "done" button of player, it takes some time, before it dissappears, because system waits before alamofire gets response to completion.

I know, that I can call it in **viewDidDisappear** method, but this way my UI freezes in another controller....

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, just needed to delete

```
    request.responseJSON { data in

        if data.result.error == nil {
            if data.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                print("Success")
            } else {
                print(data.response?.statusCode)
            }
        } else {
            print(data.result.error)
        }

    }
```

so request made, but UI is not freezing, and system is not waiting server response.